# Android IRC Connection

Tags: android

I'm developing an app, and am a newbie in terms of development on android. I want to write a script that will automatically connect to an IRC Server, Channel, Port and then when you say something in the text box it will send it to IRC server.

Any ideas on how to go about this? I did some google searches, didn't show up anything very conclusive.

IRC Connection structure:

CONNECT -> IP:PORT

CONNECT -> NICKSERV IDENITFY [username] [password]

CONNECT -> JOIN CHANNEL #bob

Once identified they can join channel and talk.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the TCP socket-based communication goes, doing it on Android should be similar to doing it on desktop computer. Therefore, you can develop your IRC communication code on desktop Java, and then copy the code over to the Android application.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

One thing to keep in mind is that you must give your Android application permissions to use the network. This is done by adding these to the application manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

However, any program that runs on Android are required to have a graphical user interface - command-line console or text-based interface simply isn't an option on Android. Therefore, you will still have to learn Android GUI programming.

You should follow [Android's Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html). The tools are free, and there is step-by-step instructions to create your first Android application.

By following the guide, you will have a very simple GUI in a short time. You can then add your text interface to the GUI and think about how to integrate this interface with your IRC code.

Comment: Cheers, I just got my test app working!